# Tesseract OCR - which coordinates are correct for setRect:(CGRect)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr, tesseract

I want to scan text (only numbers) with Tesseract OCR. I put an overlay on my `UIImagePicker` (the Camera). Here is the nib file for the overlay

[image: Nib]

The white box is the "scan area", where the user places the text to scan. The Box has the following coordinate values:

[image: Coordinates]

I put in these Coordinates in my `setRect:(CGRect)`

```
-(void)recognizeImageWithTesseract:(UIImage *)img
{

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.toCameraButton setEnabled:NO];
  });


  [self.tesseract setImage:[img blackAndWhite]]; //image to check
  NSLog(@"Breite: %f / Höhe: %f",img.size.width, img.size.height);


  [self.tesseract setRect:CGRectMake(0, 293, 320, 36)]; //optional: set the rectangle to recognize text in the image
  [self.tesseract recognize];


  NSString *recognizedText = [self.tesseract recognizedText];

  NSLog(@"TEXT: %@", recognizedText);

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tesseract OCR iOS" message:recognizedText delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yeah!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [self.toCameraButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.imageView setImage:[img blackAndWhite]];

  });
}
```

The recognized text is however always wrong, I think I pass in wrong coordinates with the `setRect` function.

Comment: Test with full camera view, if u get currect recognised text.. it will be the problem of ur cordinates

Comment: Yes thank you I did, full camera view is ok. But I dont know what are my correct coordinates. I just cant find documentation for it.

Comment: What about the documentaion in tesseract library file

Comment: which tesseract version u r using?

Comment: Im using this API https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS. I dont know which tesseract version it uses. The tesseract documentation says this: "Restrict recognition to a sub-rectangle of the image. Call after SetImage. Each SetRectangle clears the recogntion results so multiple rectangles can be recognized with the same image."

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle should be with respect to the image; not the screen of the "scan area". The capture from the camera will have much higher size than the phone's screen.

Best way to figure this out is to map your screen dimensions to the capture image size.